# NodeJS testing, async by default, with realtime results

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, integration-testing, jestjs, ava

Top async testing frameworks in node?

Bonus: parallel execution, per test file or folder, by default
Bonus: realtime results

Comment: Some overlap with the body of this closed question from 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308786/what-is-the-best-testing-framework-to-use-with-node-js
But this question includes testing inside the browser, which is out-of-scope for me.

Answer (score 1):

## AVA

https://ava.li
Futuristic JavaScript test runner

Answer (score 0):

Jest has realtime results as of version 16: http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/10/03/jest-16.html

## Jest

https://facebook.github.io/jest/

Comment: That was one of my original answers, but I used the name "Jest JS".  I'll remove mine and upvote yours.